# How to add permalinks in wordpress database with PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, permalinks

I want to insert in database with a custom PHP script from another server, posts but I need to insert permalinks and I don't know how.

In wordpress platform I have this permalink structure localhost/%postname%/ . When I post something with this script in wordpress database, title and description are ok but when I want to access new post I can't because I have no permalinks.

I have try to insert in wp_posts->post_name(in database) some custom permalinks directly to be like post-test-post.

Now I can access the post like localhost/post-test-post/ and is ok but if I want to update the post from that wordpress site the new post will have Scheduled Status and in edit area the permalink will be ok http://localhost/post-test-post/ but after I press View post, I see in browser shortpermalink localhost/?p=313 but I want to be the same like localhost/post-test-post/

Can someone help me ? Thank you!

Comment: You could try using [Custom Permalinks plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/), without touching the database.

Comment: This plugin not helps me because I need to insert posts in wordpress database with an PHP script and I don't figure out how to manage permalinks. I don't need wordpress functions I need only to insert in database what I want.